# MATLAB: how to transform one image to another image

Tags: image, matlab, function, image-processing, transformation

I am trying to transform one image to another in MATLAB, and in the meantime also get the transformation function `T(x,y)` from this operation (eg. `T(x,y) = (x + a(x,y), y + b(x,y))` ). Let's use the following figures as an example. I want to transform the square in the first figure to the circle in the other figure, and output gives me a transformation function, so whenever I use the function on the square I will get the circle.

[image]

[image]

**Functions I have looked into:**

I have looked into [imwarp](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html), but it should be only for geometric transformation (scaling, rotating, shearing). I don't think this is useful in transforming a square to a circle, while not providing any transformation matrix beforehand.

I have looked into using [imregconfig](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregconfig.html) and [imregister](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imregister.html) from a MATLAB [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/registering-multimodal-mri-images.html), but it seems to only work for images with same structure but different intensities. Plus, it doesn't give out any transformation function. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I was wondering if you found a way to do what you wanted to? I have a similar problem and can't find a way :)

Comment: Oh I kinda gave up and chose a different project haha, but I think every scenario is different so there isn't a single way of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution space for valid transformations is infinite. How do we choose the "right" one?

One possible transformation for those inputs is to translate the square `-0.5` in `x` and `-0.5` in `y`. Then scale it to double the size (`x' = 2x`, `y' = 2y`) and apply a [square-to-circle mapping function](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-square-to-circle.html). (Solution 1)

Another completely valid transformation function could run all the points in the input through the expression

`( (x == 0 || x == 1) && (0 <= y <= 1) || ( (y == 0 || y == 1) && (0 <= x <= 1) )`

and if all points pass, simply print out `"x^2 + y^2 = 1"`. (Solution 2)

Solutions (1) and (2) both produce code that seems to satisfy the case you've presented, but clearly (2) is so non-general as to be useless. I think you need to define the problem more precisely before we can start writing a solution in code.

Comment: Hmm, so I guess you are suggesting that there is no general method to get a function from transforming one image to another? My actual situation is having two cross-section images of two different brains, and I was hoping I can match different parts of the brain and also get the transformation function.

Comment: @JamestheGreat There are no general solution for general images. However, if you pinpoint your problem, you migth get an answer. Your problem is extremely common and well known in brain imaging.

Comment: @JamestheGreat What I'm saying is, there is an infinite number of possible functions to transform between two images, and you have not provided the criteria that would allow us to choose the right one.